# ExtJS : How to set combobox id?

Tags: extjs, combobox, linked-list, set

I have a little problem. At my application Im always building two linked combobox - country and towns(then country are selected - towns began to load). So i thinked - mbe write a constructor and minimized my code? Ok i did it. But i got a problem: i have 2-3 couple of this linked comboboxes on page and when i selected at second combo country, the data (towns) loads at first combo, because it has the same id. Ok - now im trying take a param id to constructor and it didnt work. How set id of combobox then i create an object?

Country combo

```
comboCountryClass = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
            fieldLabel: 'country',
            anchor: '95%',
            lazyRender:true,
            store:new Ext.data.Store({
                  proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy(
                    {url: '../lib/getRFB.php?rfb_type=countrys',
                    method: 'GET'}
                  ),
                  reader: countryReader,
                  autoLoad: true
            }),
            displayField:'country_name',
            valueField:'country_id',
            triggerAction:'all',
            mode:'local',
            listeners:{
                select:{
                    fn:function(combo, value) {
                        var modelCmp = Ext.getCmp(this.town_name_id);
                        alert(this.town_name_id);
                        modelCmp.setValue('');
                        modelCmp.getStore().proxy.setUrl('../lib/getRFB.php');
                        modelCmp.store.reload({
                            params: { 'country_id': this.getValue(),rfb_type: 'towns' }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            hiddenName:'country_id',
            initComponent: function() {comboCountryClass.superclass.initComponent.call(this);}})
```

And town combo

```
comboTownClass = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
            fieldLabel:'town',
            displayField:'town_name',
            valueField:'town_id',
            hiddenName:'town_id',
            anchor: '95%',
            id:this.town_name_id || 'youuuu',
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                  proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy(  
                    {url: 'lib/handlers/orgHandler.php?action=read&towns=true',
                    method: 'GET'}
                  ),
                  reader: townReader
            }),
            triggerAction:'all',
            mode:'local',
            initComponent: function() {comboTownClass.superclass.initComponent.call(this);}})
```

new comboTownClass({town_name_id:'townFormSearch'})

new comboCountryClass({town_name_id:'townFormSearch'})

Comment: See this screencast: http://tdg-i.com/392/ext-js-screencast-the-dangers-of-ext-getcmp for some hints on (not) using component ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the id of the component by doing the following:

new comboTownClass({id:'townComboId'});
new comboCountryClass({id:'countryComboId'});

You can specify a default id, and when you pass an id in the config param it will overwrite the default value.

Although I agree with @Upper Stage you should try to limit the amount of hard-coded id values you have in the form - you can instead grab form elements using the form name instead.

Answer (score 1):

I live by the rule: "never use hardcoded IDs."  You can retrieve a unique ID from Ext JS using

`Ext.id( null, 'someTextString' )`

You will incur more bookkeeping when you use unique IDs, but you will not run into the problem about which you write above.

Sometimes I store unique IDs locally in an object and then reference that instance variable where necessary.

```
this.idForCombo = Ext.id( null, 'someTextString' );
var myCmp = new SomeConstructor({
     id: this.idForCombo,
     ...more stuff });
```

Comment: at you solution(local - i have code at one .js file) comboTown properly created with unique id, but country combo dont seem this id at all. what problem may be here?

Comment: I don't see where this.town_name_id is set.  So, I can't be certain that [ id: this.town_name_id || 'youuuu' ] is working as you expect.  I also do not see where you are using this ID.  (Also should check the scope of this in your ComboBox constructor - probably ok.)

Answer (score -1):

```
myCombobox.id = yourId;
```